# Cannot access to shared SMB disk ask for domain password

Tags: networking, samba, smb

I has a connected hard disk to my router
I tried to connect using Files app from "other locations"
I add ((smb://user@pass:192.168.1.1/usb-04fc-FF07FF_1/))
Then it showed a dialog ask for Domain and password
The domain has no password
anyway to pass domain's password request?
any other way to connect to domain?[PROBLEM IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmeW8.png)

Comment: Your string is wrong: smb://user@pass:192.168.1.1/usb-04fc-FF07FF_1/

Comment: It should be: smb://user:pass@192.168.1.1/usb-04fc-FF07FF_1/

Comment: thanks pro
But, it showed same issue, it request password
the domain has no password
it I keep password field empty it showed error with " Failed to mount windows share: software caused connection error"

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed many articles and I tried a lot of modifications
all failed
I think it is a pug on Ubuntu 20.4 software
I tried with LMDE 4 and it was done smoothly
I hope ubuntu team solve this issue

Comment: That's strange I mount smb shared daily with 20.04... no domain here.

Comment: You can try to open an issue on ubuntu bugtracking... While usually this kind of things tend to be ignored quite often...